# Remove all extensions in a .HTACCESS file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i would like to remove multiple extensions in an application.

For example in a directory named `directory` i am having these files

- samplehtml.html
- samplephp.php
- sample.pl

I would like to access these files without extensions like

- example.com/samplehtml
- example.com/samplephp
- example.com/sample

I found this bit of code, which works for removing a single extension.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.cgi [NC,L]
```

When i try to add more extensions with this code, only the first one gets working. I have the above one extended as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.cgi [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I hope the last bit which extended has some problems. Can someone help me to resolve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes `RewriteCond` is applicable to very next `RewriteRule` only. You can have 3 rules as:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.cgi -f       
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.cgi [L]
```

**Alternative:** You can avoid all above rules with the following `Options`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
```

---

Comment: This one worked perfectly when i replaced the first line of code with the alternative specified. Using only the first part of code as it is did not work for me(It throws 404 Error).